# Nginx+web.py+fastcgi error: not found

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, web.py

The error is `not found`, and the Nginx has no errors, I have checked the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` file, it's empty. so where is the error come from ??

the python file named `app.py`, it's excuable, the content of `app.py` is same as http://webpy.org/cookbook/fastcgi-nginx, the Nginx config file named `default` located at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, I just added something into it:

```
location / {
      #below is what I added
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080
}
```

Does anyone know the reason that why the app can't route??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out, here is my Nginx configure file:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    #root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    root  /var/www/app/;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name 10.100.20.107;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
        fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx/$nginx_version;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_index app.py;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/app;
        if (-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(.*)$ /static/$1 break;
        }
    }
```